# @Font-Face cross browser compatibility issue

Tags: html, css, fonts, cross-browser, font-face

I'm having a hard time making a font look properly in the major browsers (I'm only using the Windows versions BTW for now, don't have access to Mac), I'll try to mention the code and how it behaves with each change I did to the SVG line because that's what most people suggest changing after doing some research about similar issues.

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'RobotoLight';
src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot');
src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.svg#RobotoLight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

This code makes the font look very pixelated in:
Google Chrome and Safari

However it looks fine in FireFox and IE.

This is the 2nd code (I bumped up the SVG line):

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'RobotoLight';
src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot');
src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.svg#RobotoLight') format('svg');
     url('../font/jura-demibold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.ttf') format('truetype'),         
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

Font isn't even displayed anymore and is replaced by a default webfont in: 
FireFox, Chrome and Safari

Still looks normal in IE.

Finally, when I remove the "#RobotoLight" from the SVG line, like this:

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'RobotoLight';
src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot');
src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.svg') format('svg');
     url('../font/jura-demibold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.ttf') format('truetype'),         
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

Font still isn't displayed in FireFox, but it now works properly (without Pixelation) in Chrome, Safari and IE!

So can someone help me make the 3rd code work with FireFox as well please, cross browser font compatibility is driving me insane.

ps: I'm not an experienced developer and still new to this, I bought a ready template that I'm trying to change some stuff in it to create a basic website for myself, I'm not sure if this matters but I didn't change the font-family name in the CSS sheet, I added the fonts in the proper folder and edited the SRC URL to the right path.

I assume the font-family name is for my own reference in the CSS sheet and browsers don't actually verify it.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you remove the SVG line altogether? I was under the impression that no current browser needed SVG fonts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a comma and a semicolon mixed up. The correct block would be:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'RobotoLight';
  src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot');
  src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../font/jura-demibold.svg') format('svg'),
       url('../font/jura-demibold.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../font/jura-demibold.ttf') format('truetype');       
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: What's the #iefix do after .eot? I am using this without it, and it isn't working in IE. but do you have code elsewhere that this #iefix refers to not shown??
@font-face {
    font-family: 'unicorns';
    src: url('font/unicorns.eot');
    src: url('font/unicorns.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/unicorns.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/unicorns.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/unicorns.svg#unicorns') format('svg');
}

Comment: @MarcMaxson that's to work around a bug in IE8 and older. They have a bug in their parsers for the src attribute which causes them to 404 if more than 1 font source is in the css. You could add anything instead of `?#iefix` as long as you use a question mark first.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
 url('../font/jura-demibold.svg') format('svg');
```

to

```
 url('../font/jura-demibold.svg') format('svg'),
```

EDIT: These little mistakes happen to the best of us.

Comment: Ah, yes. Each font format should be followed by a `,`. Only the last item should finish with a `;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!!  I upvoted both replies and wish I could accept both as answers, but the other reply was a bit more specific about how the last should have a semicolon so I chose as the answer. Again thank you so much, I swear everytime I have an issue with CSS it turns out a little dot or a colon is screwing everything for me lol! So far the font is working properly in all browsers now, will check with a Mac later on.